# Useful tips when measuring performance / optimizing a website?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, css

I have this website which I am about to upload. But before I do that, I'd like to check loading times, scripts loaded and other useful information that can optimize everything.

Do you have any useful steps? Maybe some plugin tool used in Chrome, FF or IE that someone can recommend?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to change the title from _validation_ to something like _measuring performance_ ... _validation_ usually refers to markup validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Firefox you can download firebug from here: http://getfirebug.com/

Then there is an add-on for firebug called yslow by Yahoo here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

This will say what you can improve on to speed up loading times etc.

Answer (score 4):

Loading times, caching, etc. are very much related to the server you are putting your site on, so I would recommend uploading it first and doing your tests on that server.

Then you can use a tool like [Google Page Speed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/) to test your site.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Yahoo! YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

Answer (score 2):

Using Firefox, I suggest you to download the [Firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), which you may use to see how long your JavaScript files are being loaded, and other useful stuff. Then you can use its addon [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), which suggests ways to improve the speed of your website.

As @jeroen said, a good part of the performance is related to the server's capacities. [Google Page Speed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/) is a very good resource to test your website after it has been uploaded to the server.

Also, if you want to check the loading time your page would take on slow connections, you can try this other Firefox Addon called [Firefox Throttle](http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx), which has been discontinued but still works.

Answer (score 2):

In the stage of development, I use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2) and Google Chrome developer tools to optimise websites.

If you want to test the site once you deployed it to the live server, I would recommend [loads.in](http://loads.in) to see where further improvements could be made.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome > CTRL + SHIFT + I > Audits > have fun.